# MQ Authentication issue: SSLCAUTH is required but SSLCIPH is blank

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

I am trying to test the authentication exits in a MQ server. All the channels has the `SSLCAUTH` attribute set to `REQUIRED`. As I know, this means each client must have SSL certificate in order to put message in channel and if they don't have valid SSL certificate, the connection will be refused. However, when I checked the `SSLCIPH` attribute for these channels, they are all blank. IBM documentation says: "The `SSLCIPH` attribute can contain a blank value, meaning that you are not using SSL or TLS. If one end of the channel has a blank `SSLCIPH` attribute, the other end of the channel must also have a blank `SSLCIPH` attribute."

So, I am totally confused here. Are the channels using SSL certificate for authentication or not. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SSLCAUTH attribute is only applicable if the SSLCIPH attribute is not blank. In other words the SSLCIPH attribute is the big switch for SSL/TLS being used. Only then will the SSLCAUTH attribute even be looked at.

Answer (score 2):

SSLCAUTH here means SSL-ClientAuthentication. This will no longer be looked at, when there is no SSL configured at the channel level for the attribute SSLCIPH.

This will be even the default configuration setting as you create a new channel. (with SSLCIPH as blank and SSLCAUTH as Required).This is also an optional attribute even after the SSL is enabled for the channels.